# Trigger hover effect over another element when hovering an element

Tags: jquery

I am having issues with this: I want to force a hover function over the image when infact hovering over the h3 element

html:

```
<p><a><img class="size-full wp-image-1236 alignleft" alt="phone-icon-red" src="..." width="50" height="50" /></a></p>
<h3>Contact Us</h3>
```

CSS:

```
img:hover{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

js:

```
$('h3').hover(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).prev('p').find('img').trigger('mouseover');
            });
```

See my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7L4WZ/166/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have workaround for your issue.

Add img class same as hover pseudo class:

```
img:hover, img.hover{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Bind mouseover and mouseout events to h3 element:

```
$('h3').on({
    'mouseover': function() {
        $(this).prev('p').find('img').addClass('hover');
    },
    'mouseout': function() {
        $(this).prev('p').find('img').removeClass('hover');
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7L4WZ/167/)

Answer (score 2):

you can use multiple jQuery event handlers:

```
$("h3").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $('img').addClass('imgHoverClass');
    },
    mouseout: function(){
        $('img').removeClass('imgHoverClass');    
    }
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7L4WZ/169/

enjoy :)